# Kubernetes - Private Repository deployment issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy an docker image from an insecure Repository using Kubernetes.
I have made couple of configuration settings in order to declare the repository as insecure and could also verify that the Repository is made Insecure.

Still while trying to deploy this sample application from the Kubernetes via

Dashboard / deployment.yaml / secret pod creation from all the 3 ways while trying to deploy the docker image from the insecure private registry i am seeing the below error . Request to provide some help in resolving the same.

```
 Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From                  Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----                  -------
  Normal   Scheduled  41m                  default-scheduler     Successfully assigned registry/private-insecure-reg to kube-node-2
  Warning  Failed     40m (x2 over 40m)    kubelet, kube-node-2  Failed to pull image "x.x.x.x:5000/x-xxx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for x.x.x.x:5000/x-xxx:latest not found
  Normal   BackOff    39m (x6 over 41m)    kubelet, kube-node-2  Back-off pulling image "127.0.0.1:5000/my-ubuntu"
  Normal   Pulling    39m (x4 over 41m)    kubelet, kube-node-2  pulling image "127.0.0.1:5000/my-ubuntu"
  Warning  Failed     39m (x2 over 41m)    kubelet, kube-node-2  Failed to pull image "x.x.x.x:5000/x-xxx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: received unexpected HTTP status: 502 Bad Gateway
  Warning  Failed     39m (x4 over 41m)    kubelet, kube-node-2  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     52s (x174 over 41m)  kubelet, kube-node-2  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: Where is your registry running, how is it installed? Where is the kubernetes cluster running, how is it installed?

Comment: My Registry is running on the Kubernetes Master node. I have followed the steps mentioned in the below docker documentation link https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/  also i have verified that the port 5000 is up and listening, i am able to pull the same image from the command prompt of kubernetes master node but while trying to deploy it from the same node seeing this error ,

Answer (score 2):

1) You need to configure docker service to use insecure registry by editing the file `/etc/default/docker` and update DOCKER_OPTS
e.g

```
DOCKER_OPTS='--insecure-registry 127.0.0.1:5000'
```

2)restart docker

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: I have added this entry and restarted docker. Also up on checking docker info i am able to see the insecure registry listed. Still i am facing the same 502 gate way error after trying to deploy. Issue still exists and is not fixed with above fix.

Comment: @ravi is your `kube-node-2` a master node?

Comment: No Kube-node-2 is not a master node its a child node. Kube-node-1 and Kube-node-2 both are child nodes. I have tried to pull the image ( on the the  child node ) from the local repository on Master . But its showing the 502 bad gate way error, How do i fix this issue? I have updated the configuration in child nodes declaring the insecure registry.

Answer (score 2):

You used plain docker to setup the registriy on the kubernetes master node. Therefore it is reachable by localhost or 127.0.0.1 only on the master node itself.
You are trying to pull the image from other nodes, according to you logfile `kube-node-2`. On that node there is no registry on localhost. But since you receive a bad gateway error, it seems like there is something listening on port 5000, just not the registry.

This is how you can solve this: Add a DNS name for the IP of the master node, so each node can reach it using a plain name. If you don't want to configure TLS certificates, you must configure each container daemon to consider your registry as unsecured (no HTTPS). See answer form A_Suh for configuration of docker daemon.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have tried adding the DOCKER_OPTS='--insecure-registry 127.0.0.1:5000' entry in both the child nodes  and can see this listed as private registry from docker info. but when i am trying to pull the image from the private repository i a seeing the 502 bad gate way error. Do i need to configure the private Registry on the child nodes too?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is local host. Use the ip of the master node where registry is running.

Comment: My Registry is running on the Master Node. You mean to say instead of using the 127.0.0.1 i should use the master node ip : 5000? i also tried it and it gives error

Comment: Yes AND configure that IP as insecure registry if you don't configure TLS with a correct trustchain.

Comment: Hi Thomas , i have made the changes as you have suggested by using the ip of the master node. Now i am not seeing the 502 bad gate way error but seeing the below error while trying to deploy from kubernetes dashboard  "Back-off restarting failed container" 
Waiting: CrashLoopBackOff

Comment: Please accept the answer since the problem is solved and open a separate question for your new problem. Provide detailed logs of the crashed pod in the new question for analysis please.

Comment: Thank you thomas for the resolution i will open a seperate question

Comment: Hi Thomas , i have posted another seperate question for this issue,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151334/error-while-trying-to-do-a-kubernetes-deployment-from-a-private-registry