# Error while trying to do a kubernetes deployment from a private registry

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to deploy a docker image from a Private repository using Kubernetes and seeing the below error

```
Waiting: CrashLoopBackoff
```

Comment: Hi, can you run the following command `kubectl describe pod $POD_NAME`

Comment: It looks like your application fails to start. Can you start your application locally using the same Docker image? Does it work?

Comment: Please provide full logs

Comment: I am not able to see any logs created Thomas

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass image pull secret to kubernetes.

1. Get docker login json
2. Create a k8s secret with this json
3. Refer a secret from a pod

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata:
>   name: private-reg
> spec:
>   containers:
>   - name: private-reg-container
>     image: <your-private-image>
>   imagePullSecrets:
>   - name: k8s-secret-name
> ```

Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Usually, the bad state caused by an image pull called `ImagePullBackOff`, so I suggest `kubectl get events` to check the root cause.

Comment: I have used the same steps and also declared the registry as insecure registry too. Still seeing the error while deploying. Earlier i got 502 bad gate way error which got resolved by properly declaring the Repository as insecure. but now seeing the CrashLoopBackOff error

Comment: Try `kubectl get events`, do you see ImagePull error?

Comment: Hi, I am still seeing the same error of CrashLoopBackoff unable to see any image pull errors. please suggest how to fix this error. I  have tried to remove the unused Pods , removed unnecessary deployments and re-deployed but still seeing the same error . Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved.
I have deleted the Registry , re-created the Registry and tried deploying a different docker image. I could successfully deploy and also could test the deployed application.

Regards,
Ravikiran.M